# Объявил объект в цикле WHILE. Не могу вызвать метод объекта за пределами цикла WHILE

Tags: java, объекты, while

```
    class Contact {
        String name;
        void call() {
            System.out.println("take it");
        }
    }
    class ContactTestDrive {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            
        int x = 8;
        Contact refc;
        
        while (x < 10) {
        refc = new Contact();
            x = x + 1;
            refc.call();
        }
        
        refc.call();
}
}
```

При компиляции выдает данную ошибку:

```
//ContactTestDrive.java:13: error: variable refc might not have been initialized
        refc.call();
        ^
```

Не понимаю в чем проблема так как тип переменной `refc` объявлен, соответственно указанно имя переменной. В цикле создан объект соответствующего типа. При переносе вызова метода объекта в цикл, все работает. За пределами выдает указанную выше ошибку. Смысл самого кода не важен, интересует причина данной ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина ошибки в том, что компилятор не aнализирует условие цикла. Он видит цикл с условием. Выполнится условие или нет - выяснится во время выполнения. С точки зрения компилятора возможна ситуация, когда выполнение в цикл не зайдет, и переменная `refc` останется неназначенной.

Comment: Я понимаю о чем вы говорите, но почему тогда при объявлении объекта массива все работает ?

Comment: int x = 0;
 Contact [] refc = new Contact[10];
 while (x < 10) {
  refc[x] = new Contact();
  x = x + 1;
 }
 refc[2].call();

Comment: @DimaB. Потому что здесь код обращается к элементу массива. Опять-таки - выяснить, присвоено ли значение элементу массива - слишком сложная задача для компилятора, поэтому он не возражает против этого обращения. Вы можете вообще убрать цикл, все скомпилируется и запустится, но во время вполнения выдаст ошибку.

Comment: Не знал этого. Собственно и поставило в тупик то что переменную массива он пропускает, а простую переменную нет. Только начал изучать, буду знать этот нюанс, спасибо за ответ!